# Unable to connect to a websites SQL server on ASP MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to connect my project to this website http://freesqldatabase.com/ (I have just created the project on my desktop and I'm trying to get the connection working so I can make tables etc.)
However I keep getting provider error 40 could not open a connection to SQL server
After realising I had to put the port number in, I was then left with "Internal connection fatal error"
This is put my connection string

```
connectionString="Data Source=sql4.freesqldatabase.com,3306;Initial Catalog=sql425174;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sql425174;Password=******" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please post your connection string, redacting your username and password?

Comment: At what point did you receive that error?

Comment: As soon as I click under data connections and then defaultconnection to try and view/make tables.

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
connectionString="Data Source=sql4.freesqldatabase.com:3306;Initial Catalog=sql425174;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sql425174;Password=******" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Comment: The comma between the DNS name and port number is actually the correct way to do it.  I'm pretty sure this won't work.

Comment: This gave me error 25, connection string was not valid, thanks, gavin.

Comment: uhhmm.. okay may be <Integrated Security = True> instead of <Persist Security Info=True> ? or maybe this can help http://forums.asp.net/t/1324024.aspx

Comment: Just gave me exactly the same error - Internal connection fatal error. :(